# How to use this Datepicker with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I would like to crawl flight data from the following page: 
https://www.airprishtina.com/de/

I managed to select the airports, but this page has a Datepicker and I don't get it how to use it programmatically.
With a Click on the Startdate Input i can open the Datepicker,

```
await page.click('#txt_FromDateText');
```

But what do I need to do to select the date/date range ?
I tried to wait for a day selector and click One, but this does not work.

```
const daySelector = '.available.flight-present';
await page.waitForSelector(daySelector);   
const elements = await page.$('.available');
const el = Array.from(elements).filter(el => {
    return el.dataset.usrDate === '2019-10-26';
})[0];
console.log(el);
await el.click();
```

console.log ist printing the element, but it does not get selected in the datepicker. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 7):

the solution is to remove the readonly attribute from the #txt_FromDateText element.

```
await page.focus('#txt_FromDateText');
await page.$eval('#txt_FromDateText',(e) => e.removeAttribute("readonly"));
```

Then you can enter any date with "await page.type".

:)

Comment: nice idea, but it is not working for me.

Comment: update: above method worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

select your date
`await page.focus('#txt_FromDateText');`

if your date is in some other format just change it accordingly.
`await page.keyboard.type('20191026');`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select a particular date, you can do it as below:

```
await page.$eval('#txt_FromDateText', el => el.value = '2021-03-02');
```